# After app clear data on Android fetched parameter value mismatching with the one in bigquery

Tags: android, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-remote-config, ab-testing

I've a remote config boolean parameter called `isSimpleBoard`

1. When open the app it fetches the parameter and its value is `true`
2. Then check the user data in BigQuery which looks like
   `key:firebase_exp_8` `value:1`
3. Then clear the app data (I use an android) and open the app again.
4. This time it fetches `false` value  But When check the user data in BigQuery it again looks like `key:firebase_exp_8` `value:1`

So, the fetch data was changed after clearing the cache, but in the analytics it still has the old value.

I expected to see `key:firebase_exp_8` `value:0` since the fetched value is `false`

1. Tried to find anything in the documentation about clearing cache
   without any success.
2. Tried to figure out how much remote config data is kept locally: The
   default is 12 hours, but it is  cleared with `app clear data`.

What can be the reason of such kind of behavior?